# Using the split

Tags: powershell, split

I have a CSV file which one of the Colums called Location. It contains "Office CityX" and "Home Office". I want to insert them into AD.

I tried:

```
$Location = -split $user.Location
$NewLocation = $Location[1]
```

It's clear that I get City1, City2,… and "Office" But I want "Home Office".
How can I split so that I get the cities and also whole "Home Office"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the location only if it contains the word `city`:

```
$NewLocation = if ($user.Location -like '*city*') {
                 $user.Location.Split()[1]
               } else {
                 $user.Location
               }
```

An alternative (if you have the names of cities instead of the word "city") would be using a regular expression like this:

```
$NewLocation = if ($user.Location -match 'amsterdam|nairobi|rome|...') {
                 $user.Location.Split()[1]
               } else {
                 $user.Location
               }
```

or, if it's only the location "Home Office" that you don't want to split, you could do it like this:

```
$NewLocation = if ($user.Location -ne 'home office') {
                 $user.Location.Split()[1]
               } else {
                 $user.Location
               }
```

Comment: Actually It was different cities but I adjusted to mine with a few -like. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks alot. Your updated Answer is 100% what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer an alternative in case it ends up being less City1, City2, City3, and more Orlando, Chicago, Seattle.

RegEx will let you split this easily enough, and will accommodate multi-word city names (rather than `,,Office New York` becoming `New`). Plus the `-split` method uses regex by default. We'll capture the desired text, so that it is returned from the split and not excluded.

```
$NewLocation = $_.Location -split ",,(?:Office )?(Home Office|(?<=Office ).+$)"
```

For a detailed breakdown of this, check out this [RegEx101 link.](https://regex101.com/r/cC5cE8/1)

Now, if we toss a few strings at that it will return either "Home Office" or anything that follows ",,Office ". Examples:

```
,,Office Seattle
,,Home Office
,,Office Chicago
```

Becomes:

```
Seattle
Home Office
Chicago
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggstion and specially that link. I should start learning RegEx! :)